# Google Developer console stack traces understand

Tags: android, stack-trace

I have an application on google store and I receive crashes in stack traces.
The problem is I can't get the line of the crash nor the file because the names not like in the java files

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:791)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:768)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:701)
at com.tech.myapp.dt.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tech.myapp.dt.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

The problem here is the name of files as

```
at com.tech.myapp.dt.a(Unknown Source)
at com.tech.myapp.dt.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
```

How to detect the line and which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Proguard to obfuscate your code, so to decode your stack trace you need your `mapping.txt` file and to either decode it manually by looking at the mappings in the file or using the `retrace` tool.  See these [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding) for how to use `retrace`.

Basically, on a Windows platform you need to do:

```
retrace.bat [-verbose] mapping.txt [<stacktrace_file>]
```

or on a Unix style platform:

```
retrace.sh [-verbose] mapping.txt [<stacktrace_file>]
```

However, as you're looking at an `OutOfMemoryError` the real cause of your problem might be elsewhere (e.g. if you leak memory elsewhere, it may be that your `Bitmap` creation isn't really the problem), it's just you see the problem when you create the `Bitmap`, so you might need to look more generally at your memory usage and/or look for memory leaks.